# create hgrc file to work on all paths on a machine, and for several repos

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I want to create a hgrc file to set the username and password for all paths on some machine, e.g no matter in which directory I am in, `hg clone some_path` will always work without prompting for a username and a password (this is for an auto-deploy script). Also, it should work for several repos, not just one.

I followed the instructions and created a file: `/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/deploy.rc`

it's contents:

```
[auth]
default.prefix= http://myrepo
default.username = myuname
default.password = pwd
```

But when I do 
`hg clone some_path` I get `abort: error: Connection refused`.

What Am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add a link to the instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work.  You can use `hg showconfig` to verify that it really is reading the config and that you don't just have a connection problem or something.

What version of hg are you using?

Also, it could be that your .hg/hgrc file is taking precedence over your global config.

Comment: apparently it didn't recognize my file. I deleted it and created another one with a different name, now it works... no idea what happened.
But the `hg showconfig` helped debug it!

Answer (score 1):

Could you get the log of the server you try to connecgt to?
It should be listed there if at least the server address is correct.
And perhaps a `hg clone -v something`